# Java.lang.NullPointerException on Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, eclipse-plugin, applaud

I just installed the AppLaud Phonegap Eclipse plugin.

But when i tried to create a new project, it just gave me a Java.lang.NullPointerException, and it didnt create my assets folder.

Am i missing a file or what? or how can i see what is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.
Selecting the "Create activity" check box on the application Info step of the wizard solves this.
I am not sure why though.